# can I make StateP from Control.Proxy an instance of MonadState?

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-pipes

I am changing some code that used to run inside a `StateT` monad to run inside of `StateP` from `Control.Proxy`. However, some of my code (e.g. the `%=` operator from `Control.Lens`) requires a `MonadState` instance. Is it safe/correct for me to just add such an instance? This seems like something that is most correctly handled by a library (in this case, `Control.Proxy`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.  The instance you want is:

```
instance (Monad m, Proxy p) => MonadState s (PS.StateP s p a' a b' b m) where
    get = PS.get
    put = PS.put
```

I just want to briefly note that in `pipes-4.0.0` (which is on Github) the proxy transformers are no longer necessary and the same extensions are outsourced to monad transformers in the base monad.  This means that instead of:

```
Consumer (StateP s p) a m r
```

... you would use:

```
Consumer a (StateT s m) r
```

This means that you would then just be able to write:

```
lift $ myLens %= f
```

However, I still plan on adding `MonadState` instances for `Proxy` anyway, although perhaps in a separate package (I still haven't decided whether to include them in the main library yet).  They would look like this:

```
instance (MonadState s m) => MonadState s (Proxy a' a b' b m r) where
    put s = lift (put s)
    get   = lift get
```

Comment: many thanks! however, this seems to be not quite correct - I get the following error:

Comment: `Kind mis-match
    The second argument of 'MonadState' should have kind '* -> *',
    but 'Proxy a' a b' b m r' has kind '*'
    In the instance declaration for 'MonadState s (Proxy a' a b' b m r)'`

Comment: removing the `r` from the Proxy type fixes the kind, but then gives another about an illegal instance declaration

Comment: @ajp You need to add the following two language extensions to the top of the file: `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}`

Comment: that wasn't quite enough in my case. I ended up needing MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, and UndecidableInstances to get it working.